# Free group 2 how much do the elements increase by with each extension of a word.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

$\mathbb{F_{\{a,b\}}} $ with $ S= \{ a,a^{-1},b,b^{-1} \}$ prove that

#$(S^{n+1} -S^n )$= 3#$(S^{n}-S^{n-1} )$

I am not so great at counting arguments I realize that at each step every element will create 3 new elements if we extend the words length by one ( noticing that there are actually 4 choices but only 3 extend the words length for each arbitrary n length word to a length n+1 word) I tried to do it by induction but it turns out that its simply gets you stuck at the same place as if you didn't bother with it.

Because $S^n $ is a proper subset of $S^{n+1} $ you can actually pull the cardinality argument apart but it leaves you with a double recursive argument to solve which is arguably more difficult then a single.

Comment: You have given the argument, what is left? Most of your text is confusing.  You are trying to count words of exactly length $n+1$, and -- as you said -- they are all formed from words of exactly length $n$. If you want an explicit map, let $wx$ be a word of length $n+1$, where $x\in S$, and look at $wx\mapsto w$. Consider how many preimages every word of length $n$ has.

Comment: I mean giving an argument is a lot different then showing they are the same isn't it?

Comment: But the map I gave is surjective, and each element in the range has the same number of pre-images.  That is about as explicit as it gets!